# Getting compilation error when using for and yield

Tags: scala

What is wrong with the following code snippet?

```
val loginInfoFuture: Future[LoginInfo] = credentialsProvider.authenticate(credentials)
              for{loginInfo <- loginInfoFuture}{ 
                println("in loginInfo future")
              } yield  Future{Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid Body Type. Need Json")))}
```

I am seeing error in IDE - `Error:(239, 17) ';' expected but 'yield' found.
              } yield  Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid Body Type. Need Json")))`

I tried a similar piece of code on REPL and that seem to work fine.

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val f:Future[Int] = Future{1}
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Success(1))

scala> for(f1 <- f) yield f1
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala>
```

For reference, below is the full function

```
  def signInUser = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async { implicit request => { 

val body: AnyContent = request.body
val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson

jsonBody match {
  case Some(json) => {

    val userSignin: Option[UserSignin] = json.asOpt[UserSignin] //check if json conforms with UserProfile structure
    userSignin match {
        case Some(signinInfo) => { //format of JSON is correct
          //Get signin info from JSON (email and password)
          val credentials: Credentials = Credentials(signinInfo.signinInfo.email, signinInfo.signinInfo.password)

          val authInfoRepository = new DelegableAuthInfoRepository(userRepo.passwordRepo)
          val passwordHasherRegistory = new PasswordHasherRegistry(userRepo.passwordHasher)
          val credentialsProvider = new CredentialsProvider(authInfoRepository, passwordHasherRegistory)


          for{loginInfo <- loginInfoFuture}{ //for returns unit. Should use yield
            println("in loginInfo future")
          } yield  Future{Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid Body Type. Need Json")))}

        }
        case None => { //No signin info found
          Future {
            Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid user. No Login info found")))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  case None => {//NO Body
     Future {
              Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid Body Type. Need Json")))
            } 
  }
} //jsonBody match
```

}//async
}//def signin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for{loginInfo <- loginInfoFuture}{ //for returns unit. Should use yield
            println("in loginInfo future")
          } yield  Future{Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid Body Type. Need Json")))}
```

This is invalid. Your for/yield needs to be in the format:

```
for {
  y <- z
  x <- y
  //etc
} yield {
  //whatever
}
```

The println after the for but before the yield is throwing you. To get the result of the println inside the for/yield, you could to assign it to a value:

```
for {
  y <- z
  a = println(y)  // will print out every y
  x <- y
  //etc
} yield {
  //whatever
}
```

for/yield blocks are stupid like that. At least there are work-arounds though!

Answer (score 2):

The following section is from scala's Future documentation:

```
def foo(): Unit = {

    val f = Future { 5 }
    val g = Future { 3 }
    val h = for {
      x: Int <- f // returns Future(5)
      y: Int <- g // returns Future(3)
    } yield x + y

}
```

You on the other hand try to do this:

```
def foo(): Unit = {

    val f = Future { 5 }
    val g = Future { 3 }
    val h = for {
      x: Int <- f // returns Future(5)
      y: Int <- g // returns Future(3)
    } {
      println("whatever") // <<<<<<<<<
    } yield x + y

}
```

The extra block of code that I point is what causing the compilation error which you did not add in your scala repl example.

This is how you can print within a Future:

```
def foo(): Unit = {

    val f = Future { 
      println("5")
      5 
    }
    val g = Future { 
      println("3")
      3 
    }
    val h = for {
      x: Int <- f // returns Future(5)
      y: Int <- g // returns Future(3)
    } yield x + y

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> > Error:(239, 17) ';' expected but 'yield' found.

simply means that the *for loop definition is wrong*

So either *with yield*

```
    for{loginInfo <- loginInfoFuture 
                //other conditions and statements
              } yield //value to be returned
```

or *without yield*

```
  for(loginInfo <- loginInfoFuture){ 
            //value updated
          }
```

are *correct for loop definitions*